# Knockout - is toFixed the right function to shift decimal points in a number

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am trying to create a computed observable from an observable. In this scenario, the observable is the precision and I want a value to be fixed to that observable value.

```
this.precision = ko.observable("2");

this.formattedValue = ko.computed(function(){
      return "567".toFixed(this.precision());
});
```

I am not able to make this work. It complains "undefined is not a function".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toFixed works on a number and not a string and the precision is also a number. (567).toFixed(2) will return 567.00.

You need to use self instead of this because inside a function this will refer to itself.

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.precision = ko.observable(2);

    self.formattedValue = ko.computed(function(){
        return (567).toFixed(self.precision());
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64SC8/1/

To shift the decimal point to the left so 567 becomes 5.67 you can use `565 / Math.pow(10, self.precision())`

http://jsfiddle.net/64SC8/2/

Comment: The code above outputs 567.00, is this the expected behavior? I want it to be 5.67.

Comment: tofixed just rounds it to a number of decimal places. eg 6.2345 with precision 2 becomes 6.23. You will need to use / Math.pow(10, self.precision()) to shift the decimal point. I've updated my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64SC8/2/ Can you please update the question and I'll update the answer

Comment: Just noticed your comment to update the question. I will do that right away!